# ContentControl change ContentTemplate on GotFocus

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have a UserControl which contains a `ContentControl`. When the user clicks this `ContentControl` I want to change its `ContentTemplate`, to make it "editable" (instead of labels display textboxes for example).
 What I have is this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ContentControl Style="{DynamicResource ContainerStyleEditable}" GotFocus="ContentControl_GotFocus"></ContentControl>
</StackPanel>
```

and in userControl resources i have

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}" x:Key="ContainerStyleEditable">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource ItemTemplateReadOnly}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource ItemTemplateEditable}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This doe not work, it seems the `GotFocus` event never fires. What is the way to to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually base my triggers of `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` instead of `IsFocused` because often the focused element usually isn't the actual `ContentControl`, but rather a control inside it's `Content`.

Also, be sure that at least one control inside the `ContentControl` can accept focus so the control can get focus. If nothing inside the control can accept focus, your trigger will never fire.